# Innovative alternatives to the classic "tabbed" window

Tags: tabs, mac-os-x

Has anyone come across any online content that jumps outside the box and re-thinks how we can organize multi-windowed content more effectively than using the classic tab bar along the top of the window?

I'm building a Cocoa application that could potentially have a lot of "tabs" open at any given time and I've always found tab bar to get a bit cluttered in these cases.

An example of an alternative would be a multi-column format, where the "tabs" are actually stacked vertically in a column alongside the main window.  The only issue I'd have with using this is that I already display a directory tree at the left of said window, so it might look confusing.

Another alternative I can think of would perhaps not be very accessible, but basically each "tab" would be a sort of bubble that goes into a panel which resizes both vertically and horizontally, and the layout optimize the positions of the "tabs" for space (like a jigsaw).

I dunno, I'm just really open minded to some fresh ideas on this since I know why I've found tab bars in similar apps to be a nuisance.

I'm trying to gain the benefits of quick browsing/navigation between open documents, and space-optimization at the same time.

(This app is a text editor/IDE)

Comment: See this mini paper on ACM Ubiquity I wrote: http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1086454

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is Tab Candy

http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/tabcandy/

Comment: Exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, thank you :)

Comment: great now vote me up :)

Comment: I can't.  It says I need to have at least 15 points :-

Comment: Goddammit, didn't mean to hit enter :)  I'm an active member on stackoverflow.com and know the system, but don't recall having to have points to vote answers up.

Comment: tabcandy site has an impressive video that shows off the many features, plus bonus footage on just how far it can go.  Definitely worth a view.

Comment: The new version of Opera has its own alternative to TabCandy, called Tab Stacking, which personally I prefer: http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/tab-stacking-is-here

Comment: Do you know why they discontinued the feature?

Answer (score 3):

Weasel Answer: Depends on the content.

If you need to compare the content of some of the windows side-by-side, tabs are one of the worst solutions.

For source code, there's an interesting prototype ([Code Bubbles](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/acb/codebubbles_site.htm)) That breaks with the convention of using source files as organization unit.

In a similar fashion, TreeStyleTab - as posted by Patrick -  exploits the hierarchy of opening tabs (at least if I understand it correctly).

So can you say anything about the data in your tabs, and how it relates?

Comment: Wow, that's interesting, but terrifying :)  Pretty much the only useful points of reference for the source files in my app will be the filename, and the file extension... maybe bookmarks.  I don't believe source code in two files looks much different side-by-side once you zoom out.  It all just looks like a bunch of lines of text. I think I'm heading towards a small workspace panel idea, with each filename put in there (grid format). The user will be able to move files in the workspace and/or merge them on top of each each (like the iPhone) to create groups that pop out when clicked.

Comment: DOn't be scared - it's jsut a prototype ;) They are right IMO that the future of code navigation != source file navigation.

Answer (score 2):

The [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5890/) plugin for Firefox is a clever implementation of multi-column, vertical tabs you described.

Comment: Awesome, that's also interesting.  I think I'll have to borrow aspects of different ideas to make something appropriate for a text editor.  The hierarchy in this example stems from the fact one web page can open another, which isn't generally something that can occur between text files.  All inspirational though :)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout fisheye tabs for firefox.... 
the user likely cannot keep a mental note on where all that stuff is anyway, so giving them a non-click hover-based view into the tabs would work quite well.
I find myself often with 30+ tabs open... expanding the tabs near the mouse cursor is both pleasing and easy to scan tabs with.

fisheye tabs (no viewable demo, you'd have to install it)
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4845/

fisheye examples: http://profs.etsmtl.ca/mmcguffin/research/expandingTargets/
(but imagine that your tabs only magnify in the x dimension.

Comment: wow, way odd - clicking that 2nd link instantly crashes my Firefox :-(

Comment: This is basically the same as the Mac OS X dock :)

Comment: @scunliffe, that page contains java applets, still the bane of our existence on the web.  While they usually work in modern browsers, it's still easy enough crash the browser.

Comment: @d11wtq - yes just like the dock, but the idea pre-dates it by quite some time.